# Cant find the get() method in MockMvcResultHandlers

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-test

I have imported the following:

```
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.*;
```

... for a controller test in a Spring Boot project but I cannot find the `perform(get(,,,,))` method.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Add comments.

import library

```
Import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.*;

Check this [link][1].


  [1]: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html
```

Answer (score 2):

The `perform()` method is a static method on: `org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders`.

Here's the full signature:

```
public static MockHttpServletRequestBuilder get(URI uri) {
    return new MockHttpServletRequestBuilder(HttpMethod.GET, uri);
}
```

And it is used like so:

```
@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/some/uri"))
    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
```